# How to upload data to Tableau Server in Python

Tags: python, tableau-api

I need to run a python script and it should upload/update a data file on a tableau server, so the dashboard linked to the datafile on the server will be automatically updated every time I run my python script. I am not exactly sure how to do that, the file I need to send to the tableau server is in a csv format - but I think the server only works with tableau files? Also I am not sure what API to be using for this purpose

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSV to TDSX: https://www.tableautim.com/playlist-video/tableau-tds-and-tdsx-files

Then, Use the `tableau-api-lib` tool for Python, https://github.com/divinorum-webb/tableau-api-lib . install with : `pip install --upgrade tableau-api-lib`,
Then create a connection to your Tableau Server:

```
from tableau_api_lib import TableauServerConnection
from tableau_api_lib.utils.querying import get_projects_dataframe

tableau_server_config = {
        'my_env': {
                'server': 'https://YourTableauServer.com',
                'api_version': '<YOUR_API_VERSION>',
                'username': '<YOUR_USERNAME>',
                'password': '<YOUR_PASSWORD>',
                'site_name': '<YOUR_SITE_NAME>',
                'site_url': '<YOUR_SITE_CONTENT_URL>'
        }
}

conn = TableauServerConnection(tableau_server_config, env='my_env')
conn.sign_in()
```

Where to publish:

```
projects_df = get_projects_dataframe(conn)
print(projects_df[['name', 'id']]
```

Publish:

```
response = conn.publish_data_source(
datasource_file_path='superstore_extract.tdsx',
datasource_name='superstore_extract',
project_id=PROJECT_ID_TO_PUBLISH_TO)
```

Inspect the outcome: `print(response.json())`

Nicely described in this article from medium: https://medium.com/snake-charmer-python-and-analytics/how-to-publish-tableau-tdsx-data-source-files-using-python-ab576a9bef4c